# Signal handlers and program control flow (order of events)

Tags: c, signals, control-flow

I've been reading about signals and signal handlers in APUE from Richard Stevens. One concept I can't grasp about them is how do they warrant synchronicity at certain times(if they even do at all, I haven't been able to find any counterexamples).

The code I'm posting does what it's supposed to: parent process reads from a file (given from stdin in a loop), sends it's content through a pipe to its child process (using memory mapping), which substitutes all instances of a word with another word, returns it back to the parent through another pipe, who then prints the changed content onto the standard output. But I don't quite get how can we be certain that the parent process got the content back safely before printing it out.

In other words, how can I be sure that the signal was caught at the right moment ? I know that a signal can happen at anytime, that is anywhere in the parent's control flow, but here I don't see any "safety measures" applied before the parent reaches a certain part of code which it shouldn't be able to execute before knowing that the child was done.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 1024


void error_fatal (char *message);

static void on_sigchld (int signo);

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  pid_t pid;            
  int filedes[2];       
  int filedes2[2];      
  char line[LINE_SIZE];     
  char *src;            
  char *nl;         
  char *command;        
  int count;            
  char *curr;           
  int left;         
  int fd;           

  struct stat stats;        
  assert (argc == 3);


  if (signal (SIGCHLD, on_sigchld) == SIG_ERR)
    error_fatal ("error signal()");


  while (fgets (line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {

      if ((nl = strchr (line, '\n')) != NULL)
    *nl = 0;


      if ((fd = open (line, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
      if (errno == ENOENT)
        {
          fprintf (stdout, "%s\n", strerror (errno));
          continue;
        }
      else
        error_fatal ("error open()");
    }

      if (pipe (filedes) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error pipe()");

      if (pipe (filedes2) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error pipe()");


      if ((pid = fork ()) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error fork()");
      else if (pid == 0)
    {

      if (close (fd) < 0)
        error_fatal ("error close()");

      if (close (filedes[1]) < 0)
        error_fatal ("error close()");

      if (close (filedes2[0]) < 0)
        error_fatal ("error close()");


      if (dup2 (filedes[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
        error_fatal ("error dup2()");


      if (dup2 (filedes2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        error_fatal ("error dup2()");


      if ((command = malloc ((strlen (argv[1]) + strlen (argv[2]) +
                  6) * sizeof (char))) == NULL)
        error_fatal ("error malloc()");
      sprintf (command, "s/%s/%s/g", argv[1], argv[2]);

      execlp ("sed", "sed", command, NULL);

      error_fatal ("error exec()");
    }


      if (close (filedes[0]) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error close()");

      if (close (filedes2[1]) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error close()");


      if (fstat (fd, &stats) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error fstat()");


      if ((src =
       mmap (0, stats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd,
         0)) == NULL)
    error_fatal ("error mmap()");


      curr = src;
      left = stats.st_size;
      while (left > 0)
    {
      if ((count = write (filedes[1], curr, left)) < 0)
        error_fatal ("error write()");

      if (count > 0)
        {
          left -= count;
          curr += count;
        }
    }


      if (close (filedes[1]) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error close1()");
      if (munmap (src, stats.st_size) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error munmap()");

      // this is the critical line I'm referring to
      while ((count = read (filedes2[0], line, LINE_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
      if (write (STDOUT_FILENO, line, count) != count)
        error_fatal ("error write()");
    }

      if (count < 0)
    error_fatal ("error read()");

      if (close (filedes2[0]) < 0)
    error_fatal ("error close()");
    }

  if (ferror (stdin))
    error_fatal ("error fgets()");


  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static void
on_sigchld (int signo)
{
  pid_t pid;            


  for (; (pid = waitpid (-1, NULL, WNOHANG)) > 0;);
  if (pid < 0 && errno != ECHILD)
    error_fatal ("error waitpid()");
}

static void
error_fatal (char *message)
{

  perror (message);


  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: No [good] reason to have a signal handler. Just loop on `waitpid` at the bottom of the parent process. This solves the sync issue. **But**, in the parent, if you blindly write _all_ data to the child before reading anything back, the parent-to-child pipe could block because the child can't keep up. _Or_ it could block because the child will block because the child-to-parent pipe kernel buffer is _full_ (i.e. the parent is _not_ reading/draining it). Your parent loop must alternate `read` and `write` to keep things flowing (possibly using `select` calls).

Comment: That full buffer thought, hadn't crossed my mind. On a related note, why would it ever be full ? If I put the `waitpid` right where I placed the critical line comment, shouldn't the two processes have no trouble exchanging data ?

Comment: Well, create a 500MB input file and run it ;-) You _don't_ get a `SIGCHLD` when the child is suspended. Only when it terminates, which is what `waitpid` waits for. `waitpid` is unrelated to the blocking problem. It knows nothing about what file descriptors (i.e. pipes) a child has open.

Comment: Consider: (e.g.) _kernel_ buffers for pipes can buffer up to 10MB before blocking a writer. parent writes 20MB to child. Child reads 10MB. Parent is blocked (waiting for the remaining 10MB to be written). Child writes 10MB. child-to-parent kernel buffer is full. child blocks. The child is draining the parent-to-child pipe, but nothing is draining the child-to-parent pipe. Eventually, child has filled its output pipe and blocks. Because parent is blocked, nothing reads back child data to unblock the child [or the parent]

Comment: Oh! So what you're saying is, the transaction is in an ongoing back-and-forth exchange ? Not like, parent says to the child 'Ok i sent everything there is, let me know when you're done, so I can have it back, I'll wait'. It's more like the parent keeps giving, yet at the same time, the moment the child gives something back, the parent prints it out, but that doesn't mean the entire exchange was complete ?

Comment: Yes--ongoing back and forth is _required_. Your code would work _if_ the total amount of data is less than the _kernel's_ internal pipe buffer. (e.g. in the above example, only 5MB has to be sent, which is <10MB). In your code, the parent will only try to read back data _after_ it has sent _all_ its data (e.g. 500MB). Its write will be blocked after 20MB [or so], the child will block after writing its first 20MB (i.e it never reads more to unblock the parent). The parent will never try to read that back because it's blocked in its write loop (i.e. it will never get to its read loop).

Comment: I understand, I'll keep that in mind in the future. So then, in this particular example, read and write functions warrant synchronicity; meaning that once we reach the read loop in the parent, read will block it if by any chance, the child hasn't written anything to it already. So my handler is obsolete, I can simply call wait at the end to fetch the child's status. Thanks !